# How to trigger a non blocking Selenium web driver launch from Tcl Shell?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, tcl, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing issues while launching Selenium Web Driver via wish shell.
I have used the following ways.

The following command launches the Selenium driver but never returns

```
exec cmd /C java -jar C:/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe
```

never returns amd blocks the wish shell.

Is there any way to launch it in a non-blocking manner.

Have also tried the following without success:

```
eval exec "java -jar C:/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe"
```

Outputs:

```
Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.6' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Whereas

```
exec "java -jar C:/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe"
```

Outputs:

```
couldn't execute "java -jar C:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\selenium\chromedriver.exe": No error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `&` as the last argument to `exec` to make the running of the subprocess be asynchronous and disconnected:

```
exec java -jar C:/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe &
```

You probably don't need the `cmd /C`, and definitely don't need an `eval`. What's more, you can factor out some of that stuff for ease of reading:

```
set selenium C:/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
set driver C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe
exec java -jar $selenium -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=$driver &
```

---

If you need to be able to detect when the subprocess finishes, you instead use a pipeline:

```
# Basic configuration
set seleniumDirectory C:/selenium
set seleniumVersion 2.45.0
# Convert to actual paths
set selenium [file join $seleniumDirectory selenium-server-standalone-$seleniumVersion.jar]
set driver [file join $seleniumDirectory chromedriver.exe]
# Use them
set pipeline [open |[list java -jar $selenium -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=$driver] r]
```

Then you can set a readable `fileevent` so that you get notified when the pipeline is closed by the other side. You might also need to read from the pipe at other times too; some experimentation might be required.

The syntax for creating pipelines is more than a bit funky. Yes, the `|` is *before* the `[list`. It's for horrible historical reasons…

Answer (score 0):

This works but will be good to know if we could fire a non-blocking cmd call.

thread::create {exec cmd /C "java -jar C:/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe"}